# Not getting correct error code for process

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I´m trying to get the return code of a batch script, which intern calls a couple other batch and exe files. When I execute the script in a CMD window and print the errorlevel, I get the correct error code, however when I do the same in C# with a process, I always get 0 as the error code.

This is my C# code

```
private Process ExecuteBatchFile(string batchFile)
    {
        Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                RedirectStandardError = false,
                UseShellExecute = true,
                FileName = "CMD.exe",
                WorkingDirectory = Constants.ToolsPath,
                Arguments = $"/c \"{batchFile} & pause\""
            }
        };
        process.Start();

        return process;
    }

batchFile = $"testScript.bat -tns {Project.TnsName} & echo Error: %errorlevel%";
```

The output I get for the echo is `Error: 0` and the process.ExitCode value is 0

If I open a CMD window and enter

```
cmd.exe /c "testScript.bat -tns MYTNS & echo Error: %errorlevel% & pause"
```

I get the correct errorlevel value.

I´m guessing it has something to do with the batch script but I don´t understand why it works in a CMD window but not in a C# Process, especially since I´m using the same method to connect a network drive and to execute an exe file.

Edit: Code without using CMD:

```
private Process ExecuteBatchFile(string batchFile, string args)
{
    Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            RedirectStandardError = false,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            FileName = batchfile,
            WorkingDirectory = Constants.ToolsPath,
            Arguments = args
        }
    };
    process.Start();

    return process;
}

batchFile = "testScript.bat";
args = $"-tns {Project.TnsName}";
```

Comment: Why run `cmd.exe` rather than the batch file directly?

Comment: The cmd.exe is executing and returning without an error which is why it should return the value 0.

Comment: I use cmd.exe because I need to execute more than one command and it does not make a difference if i execute the batch file directly, I still get exit code 0.

The  cmd.exe usually returns the error code from the command it just executed and even if what you say was the case, the echo errorlevel should not give me 0

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your attempt to do it _without_ cmd (i.e.invoking the batch file directly).

Comment: @mjwills see Edit

Comment: Can you share your batch file? Is it calling something like `exit /b 1`?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your .bat file has a line somewhere like `exit /b 1`. When running this .bat file from a cmd instance, the `/b` flag allows the .bat file to exit without closing the parent cmd process (great for running manually!).

Unfortunately, that means that when you do `Process.Start("testScript.bat");`, under the hood C# uses cmd to run your bat. The .bat file exits with the `/b` flag, signaling to the parent cmd process it shouldn't crash and therefore it exits "successfully" (exit code 0).

You have two options:

1. Remove the `/b` flag (which will correctly return the exit code .bat > cmd > `process.ExitCode`) - though this will mean that executing the .bat manually via a cmd instance will terminate the parent cmd upon exit
2. Add to your C# code to write a wrapper .bat that will pipe all args to your bat file and properly return `%exitcode%`:

```cs
private int ExecuteBatWithWrapper(string batFile, string args){
  string runnerPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(batFile), "runner.bat");
  File.WriteAllText(runnerPath, $"call {batFile} %*\nexit %ERRORLEVEL%");
  Process process = Process.Start(runnerPath, args); //Alternatively construct with ProcessStartInfo
  File.Delete(runnerPath);
  return process.ExitCode;
}
```

*(of course, if this is used in any sort of important environment, you should incorporate that into some sort of `using` statement that upon disposal deletes the runner, but this is just proof-of-concept)*

See https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/511381-system-diagnostics-process-bat-file-always-returns-exit-code-0-a#post1989782 for a similar post